# Binding ng-show to a select option in AngularJS

Tags: web-applications, angularjs

It's fairly straightforward. You can easily give show/hide functionality to pretty much any element using `ng-show="myModelName"`. In the official documentation they achieve this using a checkbox.

**Question:**
Can you use ng-show on a select option? I want to show/hide different elements depending on the option selected.

e.g.

```
<select ng-model="myDropDown">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<input ng-show="myDropDown='two'" type="text">
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You were close you will want to use == here like this:

```
<input ng-show="myDropDown=='two'" type="text">
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZbfM/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, I posted this question on the official documentation as well.

Comment: How would I implement this if Id want to show the text when one and two are selected, but not three ?

Comment: You can change it to `ng-show="myDropDown=='one' || myDropDown=='two'"` or use `ng-hide="myDropDown=='three'"`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZbfM/34/) for an example.

Comment: How does this work if ng-model=myDropDown is populated dynamically from a database using ng-repeat and the ng-value is not the same as the field you need to key off of?

Comment: @Nate maybe [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647098/initializing-select-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat) will help?

Comment: Note: we can use `ng-value` with expression expected 
ex: `ng-value="'one'"`
 
or using only `value` with string expected 
ex: `value="one"`



**conclusion: 

`ng-value` takes expression.

`value` takes string.