# Angular keep iteraction object in option with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

With ng-options the selectedCar will be a car object

```
<select 
    ng-model="selectedCar" 
    ng-options="car as car.description for car in cars track by car.id">
</select>
```

With ng-repeat the selectedCar wont be a car object and a need this object to future reference. I need to use title atribute and ng-options don't support this. How can i keep car object in option with ng-repeat?

```
<select>
    <option
        ng-model="selectedCar"
        ng-repeat="car in cars" 
        value="{{car}}" 
        title="{{car.description}}">{{car.description}}
    </option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g9yW2/2/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you're looking for: [Initializing select with AngularJS and ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647098/initializing-select-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat)
This example also helped me: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: This don't help me. I did a example. I would like to use ng-repeat with select options and keep the selected car as object and not a json. http://jsfiddle.net/g9yW2/2/