# Sorting dropddown based on a property of JSON object in Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

```
http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/

<div ng-options="f.name for f in JSONArray | orderBy:'f.name'" ng-model="selected" ></div>
```

This is just dirty representation of actual code, it might contain syntactical errors, But what my question is that I don't want whole object in ng-model. I need a property of Object say age. But if I write

```
<div ng-options="f.age as f.name for f in JSONArray | orderBy:'f.age'"......
```

orderBy won't work correctly. How can I make orderBy work with the latter one.

Answer (score 0):

To sort using a property, say age in your case, the correct syntax is this:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="f.name for f in friends | orderBy:'age'"></select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/585/)

Comment: Yes, It would work. But see I want f.age as ng-model value. Even in this case whole object would be stored in "selected". any thoughts?

Comment: @RishiPrakash Oh I see what you mean, I'm afraid I don't think it's possible using `ng-options`.

Comment: Omri Aharon ,can this problem be tackled with using ng-repeat?

Comment: @RishiPrakash I believe so, take a look here I think it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647098/initializing-select-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat