# How to add selected attribute to ng-repeated dropdown form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a form that builds out multiple widgets based on some JSON data. In part of that form is a select dropdown, and some items have different options selected by default.

ie:

```
object 1 {
    tag: "products"
}
```

The select dropdown in the ng-repeat widget

```
<select class="btn-success form-control">
    <option value="companies">companies</option>
    <option value="news">news</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="products">products</option>
</select>
```

^ Here if this was **object 1**, I'd need the products option to gain the `selected` attribute.

---

What I've tried so far, that hasn't worked, but so you can see my thinking:

HTML

```
ng-repeat="stuff in stuffs"...

<select class="btn-success form-control">
    <option value="companies">companies</option>
    <option ng-if="widget.selectedTag(stuff.tag)" value="news">news</option>
    <option value="people">people</option>
    <option value="products">products</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
this.selectedTag= function(s) {
    console.log(s);

    if (s = 'news'){
        return 'selected';
    }
}
```

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer here: [Initializing select with AngularJS and ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647098/initializing-select-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat)

```
<option ng-selected="{{operator.value == filterCondition.operator}}"
        ng-repeat="operator in operators"
        value="{{operator.value}}">
```

So in my case:

```
<option value="products"
        ng-selected="{{stuff.tag == 'products'}}">products</option>
```