# Using ng-select with and <option ng-repeat> ... causing the ng-select to point to undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-select to put the default option as the first option (past). However it shows the default as "undefined".

```
<select ng-model="yearSem" ng-show="integrated" ng-change="enrollCtrl.sendYearAndSem()">
       <option value="Past" ng-selected="true"> Past Semesters </option>
       <option value="Current"> Current Semester </option>
       <option ng-repeat="sem in offSemList" value="{{sem}}"> {{sem}} </option>
</select>
```

If I do this however I don't get the same error.

```
<select ng-model="yearSem" ng-show="integrated" ng-change="enrollCtrl.sendYearAndSem()">
       <option value="Past" ng-selected="true"> Past Semesters </option>
       <option value="Current"> Current Semester </option>
</select>
```

Thing is I need to show a few in the list and a few at the beginning. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: just try  scope.integrated = "past"

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<select ng-model="yearSem" ng-show="integrated" ng-change="enrollCtrl.sendYearAndSem()">
       <option value="Past" ng-selected="true"> Past Semesters </option>
       <option value="Current"> Current Semester </option>
       <option ng-repeat="sem.sem in offSemList" value="{{sem.sem}}"> {{sem.sem}} </option>
</select>
```

Comment: No that didn't work... It still doesn't show "Past Semesters" as the default. Also it takes the two options I placed manually out of the option list.

Comment: Edited answer. Check now

Answer (score 0):

I got it. All I did was this:

```
<select class="filled" ng-model="yearSem" ng-show="integrated" ng-change="enrollCtrl.sendYearAndSem()">
      <option ng-repeat="sem in offSemList" ng-selected="{{sem == 'Past'}}" value="{{sem}}"> {{sem}} </option>
</select>
```

Thanks goes to [Initializing select with AngularJS and ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647098/initializing-select-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat)