# angularjs select without ng-options or static options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

How, to use a static select in angularjs.

I wanna create a select ng-model with change event with statc values.

```
<form ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <select class="form-control"  name='modelid' ng-model="modelid"  ng-change="modelidchange">
        <option value="-1">select </option>       
        <option value='4'>Static text 4</option>
        <option value='1'>Static text 1</option>
        <option value='2'>Static text 2</option>                 
    </select>
</form>
```

my controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('chapter',function($scope,$http) {
    console.log('ok')
    $scope.id = modelid
    alert($scope.id)
});
```

I just wanna get de model value, but this error:

```
Error: ngOptions:iexp
Invalid Expression
```

I DON'T WANNA USE NG-OPTIONS just a static select.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Hi, check out the last part of my answer... it should solve your problems the way you expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing select with AngularJS and ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647098/initializing-select-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 3):

check this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dCFd2/), maybe it will help

```
<select ng-model="filterCondition.operator">
    <option ng-selected="{{operator.value == filterCondition.operator}}" ng-repeat="operator in operators" value="{{operator.value}}">{{operator.displayName}}</option>
```

and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650497/3033318)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to change your AngularJS Code a little bit...

**From this**

```
angular.module('app').controller('chapter',function($scope,$http){
                   console.log('ok')
    $scope.id = modelid
    alert($scope.id)
});
```

**To this**

```
angular.module('app').controller('chapter',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.id = $scope.modelid;
    alert($scope.id);
});
```

**Next your Controller doesn't match...**
In HTML your Controller is

```
<form ng-controller="mycontroller">
```

In Angular your Controller is

```
.controller('chapter'...
```

**So change it from this**

```
<form ng-controller="mycontroller">
```

**to this**

```
<form ng-controller="chapter">
```

And last but not least :-)

You need to define the function you want to call with ng-change in your controller... So change the whole code to the following...

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="chapter">
    <select class="form-control"  name='modelid' ng-model="modelid"  ng-change="modelidchange()">
    <option value="-1">select </option>       
    <option value='4'>Static text 4</option>
    <option value='1'>Static text 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Static text 2</option>
</select>
```

**Angular**

```
angular.module('app').controller('chapter',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.modelidchange = function () {
        $scope.id = $scope.modelid;
        alert($scope.id)
    }
});
```