# How to Cascade the country list passed through angular controller to view part

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```js
[
  {"name":"Afghanistan"},
  {"name":"Albania"},
  {"name":"Algeria"},
  {"name":"American Samoa"},
  {"name":"Andorra"},
  {"name":"Angola"},
  {"name":"Anguilla"},
  {"name":"Antarctica"},
  {"name":"Antigua And Barbuda"},
  {"name":"Argentina"},
  {"name":"Armenia"},
  {"name":"Aruba"},
  {"name":"Australia"},
  {"name":"Austria"},
  {"name":"Azerbaijan"},
  {"name":"Bahamas The"}
]
```

```html
<select id="country" ng-model="formOneData.country" ng-options="country in country">
 <option value="" disabled>--Select your Country--</option>
 </select>
{{country.countries}}
```

While displaying the countries in html is get the below JSON content of countries, i need to list it in the select field. So is there any alternatives .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.choice = null;
  $scope.countries = [
    {"name":"Afghanistan"},
    {"name":"Albania"},
    {"name":"Algeria"},
    {"name":"American Samoa"},
    {"name":"Andorra"},
    {"name":"Angola"},
    {"name":"Anguilla"},
    {"name":"Antarctica"},
    {"name":"Antigua And Barbuda"},
    {"name":"Argentina"},
    {"name":"Armenia"},
    {"name":"Aruba"},
    {"name":"Australia"},
    {"name":"Austria"},
    {"name":"Azerbaijan"},
    {"name":"Bahamas The"}
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <select id="country" ng-model="choice" ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in countries">
      <option value="" disabled>--Select your Country--</option>
    </select>
    {{choice}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$scope` is the 'glue' between controller and view.

```
$scope.countries = [
{"name":"Afghanistan"},
{"name":"Albania"},
{"name":"Algeria"},
{"name":"American Samoa"},
{"name":"Andorra"},
{"name":"Angola"},
{"name":"Anguilla"},
{"name":"Antarctica"},
{"name":"Antigua And Barbuda"},
{"name":"Argentina"},
{"name":"Armenia"},
{"name":"Aruba"},
{"name":"Australia"},
{"name":"Austria"},
{"name":"Azerbaijan"},
{"name":"Bahamas The"}
 ]
```

And HTML

```
<select id="country" ng-model="formOneData.country" ng-options="country in countries"></select>
```

Comment: thanks for you patience in answering but not working bro,
i need to cascade each names from the countries via select field

Comment: This is other issue in your code. Answer here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647098/initializing-select-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat