# More element in select ng-options or an output field with detalis about ng-options selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ng-options

I have have this select field:

[image]

code:

```html
<select ng-model="productForm.productDesc.idproductDesc" ng-options="opt2.idproductDesc as opt2.description for opt2 in productDesc"/>
```

where `productDesc` is a result JSON text from a query, where `productDesc` is the table and `idproductDesc` and description are two attribute of this table. I want to show another attribute of `productDesc`, such as prize (`opt2.price` in this case). I want something like that:

[image]

however: `opt2.name - opt2.price`, for example if `opt2.name` is "Patatine fritte classiche" and `opt2.price` is 1:
"Patatine fritte classiche - 1" (like in the second picture).
Otherwise an output field with the `opt2.price` of the selected element, in this way:

[image]

how can I do it?

Comment: You can do `ng-repeat` on a `option` tag. Just like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18650497/863110

Comment: mmm..I'm not sure that this is the response for my problem

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Ok..fixed it! Now it works! Thanks

Comment: My pleasure :) maybe you can post here your code as answer so it will help to other people..

Comment: ok, sure :) Posted now :) @MoshFeu

Answer (score 1):

Solved in this way:

```html
<select ng-model="productForm.productDesc.idproductDesc">
  <option ng-selected="{{productDesc.idproductDesc == productForm.productDesc.idproductDesc}}" ng-repeat="productDesc in productDescs" value="{{productDesc.idproductDesc}}">
    {{productDesc.price}} - {{productDesc.description}}
  </option>
</select>
```