# How to change ng-options to ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using angular material and can't use ng-options directive for select (because options don't creating inside select tag in angularjs material).

I have `ng-options="(k.x.y) as k.x.z for k in q"`, and how to convert it to `ng-repeat` with 'as for' syntax? should I create some new directives?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647098/initializing-select-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat . Please  check this

Comment: I think you should do a bit more research...

Answer (score 0):

need to add ng-value="..." to md-select